# How to reference shapefile in folder for input to ArcGIS Copy Features python function?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2

I am trying to write a python script that would allow me to download data and copy it to a file geodatabase.  The script currently downloads and extracts a zip folder from a FTP site.  Ideally I would like my script to then copy the extracted shapefile into a geodatabase.  The workspace in which the data is extracted remains constant. Where as the name of the data that is downloaded and extracted is variable.  How can I reference the downloaded data regardless of its name for the input argument of the [CopyFeature](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//001700000035000000) tool?

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Users\Desktop\ExtractedData'

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management( downloaded shapefile, 'C:\Users\Desktop\Test.gdb')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the folder use [ListFeatureClasses](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000001n000000) to get a list of the feature classes in your workspace:

```
import os, arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Users\Desktop\ExtractedData'
for ThisFC in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    GDBName,Ext = os.path.splitext(ThisFC) # splits out name and extension
    GDBName = GDBName.replace(" ","_")     # get rid of spaces in shapefile names
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management( ThisFC, r'C:\Users\Desktop\Test.gdb' + GDBName)
```

Comment: An ancillary goal for my script is to incorporate it into an arcgis toolbox.  Would you have any suggestions as how I could set the output for the copy feature tool to a multivalue - GetParameterAsText?  So I can copy the data to multiple geodatabases?

Comment: I always use sys.argv[] to get the parameters, but an output is slightly different.. I think you need to Get the parameter as normal then use SetParameterAsText to enforce it at the end of the script, have a read of http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002v00000004000000.htm about input/output parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should look at the first **ListFeatureClasses example** in the [online help for arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q300000023000000) for ideas on how to incorporate that function.

It has example code to:

> Copy shapefiles to a geodatabase

i.e. very similar to what you are trying to do in the code snippet that you have presented.

Comment: Beat me by one minute PolyGeo. At least the answers are consistent.